# Is it "guild Foo", "Guild Foo", or "the guild Foo"?

Tags: capitalization

Suppose there is a guild whose name is *Foo*. When I address it should I capitalize *guild*? In other words, which should I say:

> 1. He joined **guild** Foo.
> 2. He joined **Guild** Foo.
> 3. He joined **the guild** Foo.

Answer (score 1):

In role playing games, for guilds, Foo is normally the name of the particular craft practiced by members of the guild. The proper name of a guild is something like **the Guild of Tailors** with the words capitalised as shown, so the correct sentence would be:

> He joined the Guild of Tailors.

If you want to refer informally to a guild, you can do so using a genitive form of the craft, and then all words would be lower case because it is not a proper name:

> He joined the tailor's guild.

In the real world, guilds are pretty old fashioned, but there are still about 110 [livery companies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livery_company) in London, and the proper name of a guild is something like **the Worshipful Company of Merchant Taylors** or **the Honourable Company of Master Mariners**.  If you wanted to use one of these names correctly, you would have to say

> He joined the Worshipful Company of Merchant Taylors.

For a more modern example of capitalisation of names, you could look at political parties:

> He joined the Conservative Party.

Answer (score 0):

> 3) He joined the guild Foo.

is correct, because you said the name was Foo, so as a proper noun only *Foo* is capitalized.

> 1) He joined guild Foo.

is incorrect, because lower case *guild* is just a singular noun, so an article is needed.

> 2) He joined Guild Foo.

is incorrect, because this is saying that the guild name is "Guild Foo" (capitalized as a proper noun). However you said the name was just *Foo*.

Comment: Also, hʌn, not to be a stickler, but one should probably add a comma in sentence three, between "the guild" and "Foo," that is, "He joined the guild, [Foo](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/appositive.htm)."